# How to change the order of a list?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, loops

I'm using `PHP/MySQL` but just looking for pseudo-code really

How can I allow a user to change which order a list of items displays?

Say the user moves #4 to #1 do I change #4 to #0 then foreach row (1-3) increase it by 1 so it's 2-4 and then change #0 to #1?

Is this the best way?

Update: it's for a to-do list, and I won't just be swapping the order of items (i.e. swap #1 and #4 but will be moving items in front of others)

I have the items in a SQL db with item_id, task, completed, order_id

it's order_id that I need to change

Comment: we really `cantsay`..

Comment: I guess explaining better what you need might help us help you faster :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you had it right already:

```
UPDATE items SET order_id = 0 WHERE order_id = 4;
UPDATE items SET order_id = order_id + 1 WHERE  order_id >= 1 AND order_id < 4;
UPDATE items SET order_id = 1 WHERE order_id = 0;
```

To move item with order_id i up to position j (i > j):

```
UPDATE items SET order_id = 0 WHERE order_id = i;
UPDATE items SET order_id = order_id + 1 WHERE  order_id >= j AND order_id < i;
UPDATE items SET order_id = j WHERE order_id = 0;
```

To move item with order_id i down to position j (j > i):

```
UPDATE items SET order_id = 0 WHERE order_id = i;
UPDATE items SET order_id = order_id - 1 WHERE  order_id > i AND order_id <= j;
UPDATE items SET order_id = j WHERE order_id = 0;
```

Another option would be to add a `previous_sibling`. Assuming you already have the list loaded, so you know that the previous siblings are `[1 => null, 2 => 1, 3 => 2, 4 => 3, 5 => 4]`:

```
UPDATE items SET previous_sibling = 3 WHERE id = 5; #previous_sibling of 4
UPDATE items SET previous_sibling = null WHERE id = 4; # previous_sibling of 1
UPDATE items SET previous_sibling = 4 WHERE id = 1;
```

Comment: I don't know who you are, but I will find you and buy you a coffee - I love you.

Answer (score 0):

I have found that it's usually best to do sorting with javascript (i.e. jquery), if feasible, because it prevents having to hit the backend every time the user wants to resort.

However, if you want to use php to do this, I'd recommend checking out array_push, array_pop and such.  They can accomplish what you're trying to do.  See http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-push.php#56479 for an example.

Comment: well, technically, you'd be using array_slice and array_merge, but that page has an example of how to do it.

Comment: Thanks, I will be using jQuery, but would you suggest removing all of the rows from the DB, then re-adding them after re-ordering (I will probably do this using AJAX)

Comment: No, don't do any deleting when it comes to the database, just update each record with the new index for each one that changed.  Get the array in order you want it (the php way is to set up a new array and pop or push off values until you have them in the right place or else, use the example I linked), then just foreach on the array and use a query like `UPDATE mytable SET position='$index' WHERE id='$id'` This is an oversimplified example, of course, as you'd use a prepared statement or other method of sql injection prevention.

Comment: By the way, php can use a javascript array in php as long as it's in json encoding and you use json_decode.  Also, you won't need to check to see if the update is different because mysql will ignore the update if the values are identical.

Comment: It's best to let the database do the sorting, when you're already using it. When on the client side, then use JavaScript for ordering, but if you want to store the order, then you have to do this in SQL again. See my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your want to set the task with id `$task_id` to `$order_id`:

```
UPDATE `table`
   SET order_id = order_id + 1
 WHERE order_id > $order_id;

UPDATE `table`
   SET order_id = $order_id
 WHERE task_id  = $task_id;
```

And just to make sure the order ids are always continuous and without gaps:

```
  SELECT @numrow := 0;

  UPDATE `table`
     SET order_id = @numrow := @numrow + 1;
ORDER BY order_id ASC;
```

This re-numbers all order ids.